# How do I create an instance of my new entity as part of a core data migration?

Tags: iphone, core-data, core-data-migration

We have an app with a versioned core data model, and we're setting the NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption and NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption options to handle the migration at the moment.  The new version contains a `DataUpdate` entity which represents the last time the cached data was updated.  The first version shipped with some cached data, and I want the migration to create a DataUpdate with the date of that cached data, so that the app doesn't need to download it all again from scratch.

What do I need to do to get the app to create the DataUpdate during the migration?  Will I need to take over the whole migration process, or can I let it automatically infer the rest of the migration?